# Images stacking in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I am having problem in implementing owl carousel. 
The images are stacking on top of each other and not behaving as `one slide carousel`.

This is my codepen link:
http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/LRjqEB

You won't be able to see images there as they are in my local machine but it will give you guys an idea of what the problem is.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

You have the CSS files linked incorrectly and so they are not loaded. For example you have:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css">
```

You are missing the `rel="stylesheet"` from that. It should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css">
```

Place this to all your external CSS links.

See the demo: http://codepen.io/thepio/pen/ozZVbg